# Fridge compressor line - do I need to fix this corrosion?

Tags: refrigerator, appliances, corrosion

Moving into a new house, cleaning previous owner's cat's hair from every crevice.

This fridge is approximately 3 years old. Opening the panel to clean it out - there was a *lot* of cat hair stuck to everything - I noticed this corrosion on a copper line at the bottom of the frame (presumably a compressor line).

The fridge operates normally, as far as I can tell, and cools effectively.

Is this something to be concerned about in the short term? Do I need to plan an eventual service call?

[image: Corrosion on fridge compressor line]

Comment: At only 3 years old, the fridge _might_ still be under warranty. There's no guarantee the warranty is transferable, but it's worth contacting the manufacturer to find out. If you give them the model/serial number, they'll tell you. If it is still under warranty, ask them to send a tech out to inspect it. I'd continue to vacuum it out to get rid of as much cruft & cat hair as possible before the tech gets there. If it's no longer under warranty, then by all means continue with a DIY solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are speaking of the green marks on the lower line, that looks like minor surface oxidation of the copper.

Clean it off with some [scuffing pads](https://www.uline.com/Product/Detail/S-18434/Scouring-Pads-and-Sponges/3M-Scotch-Brite-Heavy-Duty-Scouring-Pads-86?pricode=WB0515&gadtype=pla&id=S-18434&gclid=CjwKCAjw1t2pBhAFEiwA_-A-NEasoXZrrfL38NHGYgBoUl-Dc_nHEElA2Wp3i1oDyYIrSnXTkwNsYBoCkjsQAvD_BwE). Be sure the copper is not touching other metal.

It looks as if some moisture got on the copper and dripped. That probably helped the oxidation.  It should not be a problem unless there is something causing the moisture to continue.

Comment: It's weird to see copper corrosion on the *top* of a line, though!

Answer (score 2):

That green stuff is oxidation that's caused by the piping's exposure to moisture. It's small enough not to suggest a leak, could be one time cat urine. Get some emery paper and just rub the oxidation or the pipe.